# Send data to Kafka topics based on a condition in Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I want to change the Kafka topic destination to save the data depending on the value of the data in SparkStreaming.
Is it possible to do so again?
When I tried the following code, it only executes the first one, but does not execute the lower process.

```
(testdf 
.filter(f.col("value") == "A")
.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as value")
.writeStream
.format("kafka")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint_1")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","~~:9092")
.option("topic", "test")
.option("startingOffsets", "latest")
.start()
      )
            
(testdf 
.filter(f.col("value") == "B")
.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as value")
.writeStream
.format("kafka")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint_2")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","~~:9092")
.option("topic", "testB")
.option("startingOffsets", "latest")
.start()
      )
```

Data is stored in the topic name test.
Can anyone think of a way to do this?

I changed the destination to save such a data frame.

```
|type|value|
| A  |testvalue|
| B  |testvalue|
```

type A to topic test.
type B to topic testB.

Comment: I can go as long as it's not a streaming process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest versions of Spark, you could just create a column `topic` in your dataframe which is used to direct the record into the corresponding topic.

In your case it would mean you can do something like

```
testdf 
  .withColumn("topic", when(f.col("value") == "A", lit("test")).otherwise(lit("testB"))
  .selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as value", "topic") 
  .writeStream .format("kafka") 
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint_1") 
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","~~:9092")
  .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

thx mike.
I was able to achieve this by running the following code!

```
(
testdf 
  .withColumn("topic",f.when(f.col("testTime") == "A", f.lit("test")).otherwise(("testB")))
  .selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as value", "topic") 
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka") 
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint_2") 
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","9092")
  .start()
)
```